How to ignore peer certificate expiry in Java?
I am working on a Java product which validates peer's TLS certificate chain using the validate() method of sun.security.validator.Validator. Some peers have expired certificates. The product has to ignore expiry errors if the user so chooses. I can catch the CertificateExpiredException and ignore it. But I am not sure if this is the last check in the validate() method and if the other checks passed before an expired certificate was encountered. Is it safe to ignore expiry of certificates this way ? Is there a better way to implement this ?

"Is it safe to ignore expiry of certificates this way?" Let me rephrase this: Can we guarantee that no adversarial actor ever gets access to the private key of a client cert in the future?

@GenerousBadger , I do understand the implication of the private key being lost. However, this is a requirement from customer. When I asked "is it safe", I meant to ask if this is a proper way to ignore just the certificate expiry and have all other certificate chain validations happen.

A validation has only two results: valid or invalid. So valid but expired is not a result to be expected from a validator.
Therefore sun.security.validator.Validator is probably not the class you want to use, especially if you would have to rely on it's implementation details. This could lead to problems in future versions of Java.
You could copy it's sourcecode (or the one of SimpleValidator if that is enough) and modify it to your needs.
Or when you check the sourcecode you see that the code signing variant will not check expiration dates. But although it is tempting to just use that variant of a Validator be careful, it could have other side effects as well!
Maybe a better alternative could be to offer the variants of the Validator as selection for your users, with all the implications.
From the JavaDoc of Validator:

Variant controls additional extension checks. Currently supported are five variants:

VAR_GENERIC (no additional checks),
VAR_TLS_CLIENT (TLS client specific checks)
VAR_TLS_SERVER (TLS server specific checks), and
VAR_CODE_SIGNING (code signing specific checks).
VAR_JCE_SIGNING (JCE code signing specific checks).
VAR_TSA_SERVER (TSA server specific checks).
VAR_PLUGIN_CODE_SIGNING (Plugin/ WebStart code signing specific checks).


(Note that the difference in the number five and the actual length of the list is part of the source)
